# importing the excel data into database table using php

Tags: php, mysql, excel

problem is in my excel 369 rows are there. when I echo/print that data it showing correct but when I am inserting same data in DB table in inserted only 18 - 30 records.

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    $file = $_FILES['csv_file']['tmp_name'];
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    if ($file == NULL) {
    error(_('Please select a file to import'));
    redirect(page_link_to('excel_data_upload'));
    }else {
        $conn = connect();
        while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false)
        {
            $num3 = $filesop[3];
            $num8 = $filesop[8];
            $num9 = $filesop[9];
            $num20 = $filesop[20];
            if($num3!='ExpiryDate' &&$num8!='VCNO' &&$num20!='TotalB2CAmount' && $num9 !='STBNO'){

                $insertAgent =  mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO `upload_billing_data` 
                (`vc_number`,`stb_number`,`operator_id`,`expiry_date`,`monthly_bill_amount`) 
                VALUES ('$num8','$num9',140,'$num3','$num20')");

                if($insertAgent)
                {
                    echo 'succss';
                }else{
                    echo 'error';
                }

            }  
        }
        close($conn);

    }
}
```

I am fetching from the excel data. I want to insert all records

Comment: If records are inserting means that SQL query is working. Please check your `if(...` condition. This may be false for non-inserting rows.

Comment: Suggestion: don't open and close database connection in each iteration of `while` loop, move `$conn = connect();` and `close($conn);` outside of the `while` loop.

Comment: Some records might have single quote `'` that's why they do not get inserted

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all! If, for example, any value contains a single quote or ends with a backslash, your query would fail.

Comment: if condition is not a problem i checked

Comment: connect() I changed that now I got 120 records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the code as below and you might get to save all data using one query to the database:

```
$query_insert = array();

while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false) {
   $num3 = filterString($filesop[3]);
   $num8 = filterString($filesop[8]);
   $num9 = filterString($filesop[9]);
   $num20 = filterString($filesop[20]);

   if ($num3!='ExpiryDate' &&$num8!='VCNO' &&$num20!='TotalB2CAmount' && $num9 !='STBNO') {
      $query_insert[] = "('{$num8}', '{$num9}', 140, '{$num3}', '{$num20}')";
   }  
}

// If no row matched your if, then there will be no row to add to the database
if (count($query_insert)>0) {
   $conn = connect();

   $query_insert_string = implode(', ', $query_insert);

   $query = "INSERT INTO `upload_billing_data` (`vc_number`, `stb_number`, `operator_id`, `expiry_date`, `monthly_bill_amount`) VALUES {$query_insert_string};";
   $insertAgent = mysqli_query($query);

   // The rest of you code 
   ...

   close($conn);
}



// This function makes sure that you string doesn't contain characters that might damage the query
function filterString($string) {
   $string = str_replace(array("\'", '"'), array('', ''), $string);
   $string = filter_var($string, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
   return $string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this modified code

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    $file = $_FILES['csv_file']['tmp_name'];
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    if ($file == NULL) {
    error(_('Please select a file to import'));
    redirect(page_link_to('excel_data_upload'));
    }else {
        $conn = connect();
        while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false)
        {
            $num3 = $filesop[3];
            $num8 = $filesop[8];
            $num9 = $filesop[9];
            $num20 = $filesop[20];
            if($num3!='ExpiryDate' &&$num8!='VCNO' &&$num20!='TotalB2CAmount' && $num9 !='STBNO'){

                $insertAgent =  mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO `upload_billing_data` 
                (`vc_number`,`stb_number`,`operator_id`,`expiry_date`,`monthly_bill_amount`) 
                VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($num8)."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($num9)."',140,'".mysqli_real_escape_string($num3)."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($num20)."')");

                if($insertAgent)
                {
                    echo 'succss';
                }else{
                    echo 'error';
                }

            }  
        }
        close($conn);

    }
}
```

BY using mysqli_real_escape_string() you will be able to avoid sqlinjection issues and you will be able to handle issue of quotes which might be causing an issue.

in your else block where you are `echo "error"`. you can use `mysqli_error($conn);` to get exact what error is occurring while performing an insert